# Accessing an array property on every object in an array, with ng-repeat

Tags: arrays, angularjs, object, indexing, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've spent ages trying to solve this, and I can't...

- I have an array: `clubData`.
- In that array is a series of objects, which represent individual football clubs.
- In each club object, is an array assigned to the property `squad`.

Here's a sample of `clubData`:

```
[{
        "league": "0",
        "id": "0",
        "name": "AFC Bournemouth",
        "codeName": "afc-bournemouth",
        "nickName": "Cherries",
        "dateFounded": "1899",
        "stadium": "Dean Court",
        "manager": "Eddie Howe",
        "squad": 

        [               
            {"clubCode": "afc-bournemouth",
                "firstName": "Artur",
                "lastName": "Boruc",
                "nationality": "pl",
                "country": "Poland",
                "position": "gk",
                "shirtNumber": "1",
                "age": "36"},

            {"clubCode": "afc-bournemouth",
                "firstName": "Glenn",
                "lastName": "Murray",
                "nationality": "gb-eng",
                "country": "England",
                "position": "fw",
                "shirtNumber": "27",
                "age": "32"}
            ] 

    }, {
        "league": "0",
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Arsenal",
        "codeName": "arsenal",
        "nickName": "Gunners",
        "dateFounded": "1886",
        "stadium": "Emirates Stadium",
        "manager": "Arsène Wenger",
        "squad": [ etc... ]
    }
]
```

I want to run an ng-repeat on an md-card (Angular Material directive), so every object (player) in every `squad` is repeated as a card.

---

### My current method:

I used an outer and inner div with two separate ng-repeats. The issue with this is it necessarily repeats the outer div, which causes a 'break' at the end of every outer div repeat, when I just want the inner div repeated as individual units.

My HTML currently looks like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="item in clubData" layout="row" layout-wrap>

    <md-card ng-repeat="player in item.squad" layout="row" layout-wrap>

        <md-card-header>
            <md-card-avatar>
                <div class="clubavatar club-icon-{{player.clubCode}}"></div>
            </md-card-avatar>
            <md-card-header-text>
                <span class="md-title">{{player.firstName + " " + player.lastName}}</span>
                <span class="md-subhead"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{player.nationality}} nationid  md-whiteframe-1dp"></span>{{player.country}}</span>
            </md-card-header-text>
        </md-card-header>

    </md-card>

</span>
```

---

### My attempted (and failed) solution:

Ideally, I want to come up with an expression in ng-repeat that will iterate through the elements but only print the squad arrays.

I *thought* something like this might work (but it doesn't):

```
<md-card ng-repeat="player in clubData[$index].squad">{{player.name}}</md-card>
```

Logically (to me) that would print out...

```
<md-card ng-repeat="player in clubData[0].squad">{{player.name}}</md-card>
<md-card ng-repeat="player in clubData[1].squad">{{player.name}}</md-card>
<md-card ng-repeat="player in clubData[2].squad">{{player.name}}</md-card>
```

Perhaps I'm misusing `$index`?

If there's something I'm missing, or an alternative working solution, would really appreciate someone's help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Paulos3000/Lt7aP/2340/ (a rough approximation)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've done some research on reduce() but it confuses the hell out of me... any chance you could explain what you've done in this example? ie. break it down a bit? :/

Comment: Sure, I'll update my answer and provide you alternate fiddle for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks - definitely a lot clearer. However, when I implement it in my controller it crashes my app, the console reads `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`. 'Undefined' in this instance being `clubData`. I checked the clubData array though and it's fine, I called in it in an expression and it printed the whole thing. Do you know why this is not working?

Comment: This error suggests that the variable is not defined this means that there is some issue with the variable initialisation.As you can see it works with the JS fiddle that is attached to my answer so can you modify your jsfiddle or provide me some of your controller code where you initialise your clubData array. so I can look and see what's going on

Comment: There's so many files and they're so interdependent I don't know how to get the original across to you. Thanks for your help anyway, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

Inside your controller

```
 $scope.players = clubData.reduce(function(a,c){
                      return a.concat(c.squad);
                  },[]);
```

Using forEach

```
 $scope.players = [];

  $scope.clubData.forEach(function(c) {
     $scope.players = $scope.players.concat(c.squad);
  });
```

and on view:

```
<md-card ng-repeat="player in players">{{player.name}}</md-card>
```

Response to your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/2342/

Solution using forEach: https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/2344/

> Explanation - reduce

reduce is higher order function, very common with functional programming. it takes following form ...

es6 (or you can use babel for support):

```
//Will return final value of accumulator!
<array>.reduce(function(accumulator,current){
   //accumulator: accumulated result for each iteration
   //current: current item for given iteration

   //accumulator is empty array or array of players
   //we just concat current's squad array 
   var mergedPlayers = accumulator.concat(current.squad);
   //This return will set accumulator to returned value
   //for next iteration.
   return mergedPlayers;
},
[]  //Default accumulator empty array.
);
```

you can also use `lodash`, slight syntax change

```
_.reduce(<array>,function(accumulator,current){
 /* your awesome code goes here*/
},[]);
```

Hope this helps!